# 404 not found error, certbot generating tls certificate

Tags: ubuntu, certbot

Through installing TLS certificate of turn server, running the command below and got the error message as shown pic, searched on net but couldn't solve..

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http --deploy-hook "systemctl restart coturn" -d mydomain.com
```

I see certbot service tries access some endpoint, but why it expects to its existed all of a sudden?
what do I suppose to do?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (virtual machine)

[image: blured some unsafe and unnecessary details]

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML. And web knows X509 certificates, not TLS certificates

Answer (score 1):

In order to verify that you actually control the domain you are requesting a certificate for, Let's Encrypt is using a HTTP-based challenge mechanism. Basically, Let's Encrypt is giving `certbot` a long random string, and for the duration of the challenge procedure, `certbot` will be temporarily acting as a web server so that the validation server at Let's Encrypt can immediately attempt to contact it and verify that the exact same challenge will be retrievable from the HTTP server in port 80 on the specified hostname.

The error messages are what was received by the Let's Encrypt validation server as it tried to retrieve the challenge string from your `certbot` via HTTP. It appears that there is already a web server running on port 80 of the hostname you requested the certificate for, and it responded with a 404 error when Let's Encrypt sent a HTTP request for the challenge URI on that host.

If you use `sudo certbot certonly --standalone`, you should first stop anything that is using port 80 on that server, so `certbot` will be able to spin up its temporary HTTP server in order to respond to the challenge.

If you cannot do that, you might be able to use `sudo certbot certonly --webroot` instead, and configure your existing HTTP server to allow incoming requests to URI `/.well-known/acme-challenge` on port 80 of your server, and place the challenge in there manually (or configure `certbot` to put it in the directory that maps to that URI, by specifying the `--webroot-path /root/of/your/HTTP/namespace`).